How to see the arn of a launch tempate in the management console in aws?
How to see the arn of a launch tempate in the management console in aws?
I can not find it.

You can use this format
arn:aws:ec2:${Region}:${Account}:launch-template/${LaunchTemplateId} or arn:aws:ec2:region:account-id:launch-template/{LaunchTemplateId}.
Not sure you can find the ARN on AWS Console, but if you need to retrieve using CLI or so, the above format going to work for you.

I couldn't find it in the Management Console, and listing Launch Templates with the AWS CLI didn't show it either.
However, Control access to launch templates with IAM permissions - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud says:

A launch template has the following ARN:
"Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:region:account-id:launch-template/lt-09477bcd97b0d310e"

That lt- ID at the end can be found in the Management Console as the Launch template ID.

Just realized, that terraform identifies it with lt-
